# Property Observer vs homemade setters

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

In a an aurelia view-model, I have some properties that need to be updated everytime other properties are changed.

In my knowledge, there are two distinct ways to do that.

## Method 1 : propertyObserver

```
export class Foo {
    propX : number;
    bindingEngine : BindingEngine;

    bind() {
        this.bindingEngine.propertyObserver(this, 'propX')
            .subscribe((newV, oldV) => { this.updateOtherProperty() });
    }

    updateOtherProperty() {
        //...
    }
}

// usage
foo.propX = 5 // updateOtherProperty gets called
```

## Method 2 : homemade setter

```
export class Foo2 {
    propX : number;

    setPropX(value : number) {
        this.propX = value;
        this.updateOtherProperty();
    }

    updateOtherProperty() {
        //...
    }
}

// usage
foo.setPropX(5) // updateOtherProperty gets called
```

What is the best method and why ?

Answer (score 1):

Use computed properties:

```
import { computedFrom } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class MyClass {

  @computedFrom('propX', 'propY') //update this property whenever propX or propY change
  get myComputedProp() {
    //do your magic here!
    return this.propX + this.propY;
  }

}
```

Usage:

```html
<div>${myComputedProp}</div>
```

More information at: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-computed-properties/1

Comment: Mmh interesting. I have probably seen it in the docs but I had not thought about it.

Answer (score 1):

The compact Aurelia way to *observe* members of your view-model is with observables which act like the bindables. It's the equivalent of your "Method 1" but less verbose because of convention, plus you don't have to track any `Disposable` leftovers.

```js
import {observable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Foo {
    @observable
    propX : number;

    propXChanged(newVal, oldVal) {
        //...
    }
}
```